# This page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times. When I created a middleware to check login authentication

Tags: php, laravel

I created a middleware to check login authentication, but when I redirected the redirect, I got this error.

middleware/TwoFA.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    if(Auth::check()){
        if(auth()->user()->is_verified == true){
            return $response;
        }else {
            return redirect('/verifyOTP');
        }
    }
    return $response;
}
```

kernel.php

```
'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TwoFA::class,
    ],
```

web.php

```
    Route::get('verifyOTP', 'VerifyOTPController@showVerifyPage')->name('verify');
Route::post('verifyOTP', 'VerifyOTPController@verify');
Route::group(['middleware'=>'TwoFA'], function (){
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@doashboard')->name('doashboard');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
use App\Http\Middleware\TwoFA;
```

to web.php

and change

```
Route::group(['middleware' => TwoFA::class], function () {
     Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@doashboard')->name('doashboard');
});
```

Comment: It didn't work, as if I was caught up in the infinite loop of the function handle

Comment: Did you removed your middleware and handle? I used this before and it was working.